# HTML file on localhost

Tags: angularjs

As I am new to angularjs and I have made one small app using ui-router in angular and I want to run it on localhost.Can someone please tell how to do that? I am using windows7. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about [sublime text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) as the text editor and [sublime server](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeServer) to provide the localhost. You need to install [package control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) also for sublime text.

Comment: @Shivam, which backend language you are aware of means PHP,Node.js?

Comment: I know java in backend.

Comment: have you written this code in any editor?

Comment: I use a simple node module called http-server. Allows me to start up a simple static file server from any directory. May be helpful.

Comment: @RakeshBurbure ..I have written this code in visual studio code editor

Comment: @Naren ..it worked.. thanks

Comment: @Shivam you're welcome, Sublime text is an awesome tool for web development, I highly recommend [sublime text tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLnpHn493BHEYF4EX3sAhVG2rTqCvLnsP) for getting the best usage of the tool

Comment: Yes Naren.. i think the same.. thanks for ur suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [grunt](https://gruntjs.com/) or [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) task runner with angular for development process. Configuring them will provide you excellent livereload watcher feature which is really helpful for development.

But if you just want to static host your angular file you can do it with

python:
install python first

then cd to folder with angular file in your cmd and try:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

with NodeJS:
install nodeJS and NPM then try following in cmd

```
npm install http-server -g
```

and then cd to directory with angular files

```
http-server
```

Note that here any page name index.html in folder will be consider as default page on loading localhost url

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to switch to Angular 4, because in my opinion is little easier and more optimized and you setup enviroment via nodejs with nmp, I learend that from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htPYk6QxacQ